# Elasticsearch .net v7.1 issue after update

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I have updated my project into last elasticsearch version. But after this, when I trying to get data from my elastic, I have next exception.
My nugets: 
   Elasticsearch.Net v7.1.0,
   NEST 7.1.0
Before update, when I using 6.7.0 elastic, I haven't got this issue.

1. When I trying to get 900 elements, it works good.
2. When I trying to get more than 1000, have this exception.
3. I have set "max_result_window" : 500000

`Exception has occurred: CLR/Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException
An exception of type 'Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'expected:'Number Token', actual:'null', at offset:169'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonParsingException : expected:'Number Token', actual:'null', at offset:169`

Comment: It seems that the result is very huge. max_result_window is the HTTP limitation. you can easily increase it. or you can use scroll api.

Comment: But the same requests in the 6.x elasticsearch works fine. max_result_window  - i have increased this field, but it still not working. Maybe you knows what property I should change?

Comment: Resolved!
The serializer in 7.x is much faster than in 6.x, however it is stricter. And if you have field with type int, but response have nullable int, you should change field into nullable. And all will be fine.

Comment: @RomaPavliuk - This is the problem for me, too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The serializer in 7.x is much faster than in 6.x, however it is stricter. And if you have field with type `int`, but response have nullable `int`, you should change field into nullable. And all will be fine.